# How to cleanup jest beforeEach and afterEach in a loop

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a loop that inside has `beforeEach` and `it`. Whenever I run, I can see that `beforeEach` and `afterEach` functions persist in the loop. How can I remove them?

```
describe('test', () => {
    ['1', '2', '3'].forEach(each => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        console.log(`before ${each}`)
      })
      it('test 1', () => {
        console.log(`test1 ${each}`)
      })
      it('test 2', () => {
        console.log(`test1 ${each}`)
      })
    })
```

I'm getting on the console:

```
before 1
test 1
before 1
test 2
before 1
before 2
test 1
before 1
before 2
test 2
before 1
before 2
before 3
test 1
before 1
before 2
before 3
test 2
```

Comment: Because the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` functions are scoped to the `describe` block level-- if you want them removed after each `forEach` run, you'll need to wrap each loop within a new `describe` block, I think.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but I was wondering if there is a function to delete the beforeEach and afterEach that are run. I want to conserve the describe

Comment: Nothing that I see in [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html#beforeeachfn) for `beforeEach` -- thus, I suspect any means available to do this, if it exists, will be fragile as it is undocumented.  Hopefully someone can come along and prove me wrong...